# possible to determine browser language setting on site page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is it possible to determine the browser language setting of a guest user on an external site from Apex or VF?

I'm leveraging custom labels and they seem to respond to the browser language setting of a guest user, however I also have some dynamic picklist values that I need to display in the correct language as well. Has anyone had experience with this or know of a way to get the browser language setting value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The normal way to get that value is by [Accept-Language](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#z12) request header.

I think this is not possible to get by Apex.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_pages_pagereference.htm#RequestHeadersSectionTitle

```
//this is returning null
ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Accept-Language');
```

A possible workaround could be to get it on VF using [this technique in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3335420/356042)

```
var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language; //works on IE/CH/FF
if(language){
    nowDoSomethingWithIt(language);
}else{
  //other browsers gonna be a little tricky
  $.ajax({ 
    url: "http://ajaxhttpheaders.appspot.com", 
    dataType: 'jsonp', 
    success: function(headers) {
        language = headers['Accept-Language'];
        nowDoSomethingWithIt(language);
    }
  });
}
```

Once you have the language you could `rerender` the `picklist` using a

```
@remoteAction
```

Comment: ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Accept-Language'); worked fine for me, thanks!

Comment: Great @PhilB, which API version are you using?

Comment: That class is using API version 25

Comment: Just implemented ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Accept-Language'); in a multilingual site and it's working for Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Edge.